# Timer 555 AC square wave

Tags: ac, 555, square

Im currently trying to build a square wave circuit using the 555 Timer (see picture). Currently it is producing a square wave between 0 to 5V, duty cycle is about 50% and a frequency of about 50kHz.
(I am later on planning to add a integrator circuit on order to produce a triangular wave).

**My question is**: How do I make a "AC square wave" if possible. For example, make the output +- 2.5V.

[image]

Comment: You said it is already producing a square wave, so what's the question? You want it to produce a square wave from -2.5 V to 2.5 V or something? Please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: You need negative voltage power supply + comparator.

Comment: set your ground reference to 2.5 V below Vcc

Comment: Capacitors block DC and are used for AC coupling.

Comment: Konrado, @Justme brings up a point. It's simple to just add a cap to the output (with a weak galvanic resistor to ground) in order to shift the output. But then a lot depends on what the load is like and how long you can wait for the output to settle down. Load details become important and you've not said much about that. Do you need significant current compliance at your \$\pm 2.5\:\text{V}\$ output?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If "square" means accurate 50% duty cycle, you should have the oscillator generate twice the frequency you need and divide by 2 with a logic circuit.

Comment: For shifting the output from all positive to +/- then [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55644/voltage-shift-to-negative-range) seems right.